# Why wont Ajax pick up my vars for posting to Mysql?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have coded am html form, and used jquery validation methods. Then when the form is valid i am using Ajax to send data to mysql database. The only issue is none of the data entered into the form is being processed, perhaps i am missing something? Before you say i need to escape the data on the php code, i have removed this for the time being to keep it simple.

```
<form id="photoSubmit" method="get" action="">

<div id="close-form">close</div>
<label><em>Fields marked * are required</em></label>
<div>
    <label>FIRST NAME *</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" autocorrect="off"/>
</div>
<div>    
    <label>SURNAME *</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" autocorrect="off"/>
</div>
</form>



    $().ready(function() {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() {
            var firstName     = $('#firstName').attr('value');
            var surname     = $('#surname').attr('value'); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert_ac.php",
            data: "firstName="+ firstName + "&surname=" + surname,
            success: function(){
                window.location.replace("thank-you.php");
            }
        });
    return false;
        }
    });




        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#photoSubmit").validate({
            rules: {
                firstName: "required",
                surname: "required"

            },
            messages: {
                firstName: "Please enter your first name",
                surname: "Please enter your surname"
        });


    });

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="fub005_mif"; // Database name
$tbl_name="snappingcities"; // Table name

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

$timedate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$firstName=$_POST['firstName'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(firstName,surname)VALUES('$firstName','$surname')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){

}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

personally i prefer to let jQuery create the query string, so create an object yourself:

```
data: {
     firstname: $('#firstName').val(),
     surname: $('#surname').val()
}
```

also if you use .attr('value') it may be looking for an actually populated value attribute, whereas .val() will give you the current value of the element - i think this is your main issue here.

Comment: After changing the code, i also realised the .val was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, very simple.

change this:

```
data: "firstName="+ firstName + "&surname=" + surname
```

to this:

```
data: $("#photoSubmit").serialize()
```